# Trace Dependencies for user defined range and list Source Cell/Dependency Cell in separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, dependencies

I have a range of cells (user defined) that I want vba to tell me which cell(s) these are linked to.
Every source cell can be linked to 1 or multiple cells.

I have the code so far that it

- prompts the user for the range
- checks that only 1 row is selected.
- counts the amount of cells in the range.
- creates a separate sheet to list the dependencies.

I am struggling to have the each source cell listed horizontally and 2 rows below the dependency cell(s).

Option Explicit
Sub ListDependents()

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim n As Long, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Use InputBox to prompt user for range.
'Test for cancel and a single-cell selection.

Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
    Title:="Please select a range", _
    Prompt:="Select range", _
    Type:=8)

On Error GoTo 0

'Test for cancel.
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Test for single-cell selection.
'Remove comment character if single-cell selection is okay.

If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "You’ve selected more than 1 row. Please select contiguous cells per row only."

End If

'rng.Select to confirm selection
MsgBox rng.Address

'count cells to be reviewed for dependencies
For Each cell In rng.Areas
    n = n + cell.Cells.Count
Next cell

Sheets.Add().Name = "Dependents"

'add first cell of range in B1, second in C1 etc until end of range
'then add first dependent of first range cell in B3, second in C3 etc

If n > "0" Then
  i = 1 + i
   Sheets("Depentent Test").Cells(2, i) =



End Sub
```

Source Sheet
[image: Source Sheet]
Destination Sheet
[image: Destination Sheet]

Comment: So you want first source cell in B1 and dependents in B3, B4 etc? Loop through dependencies and use a row variable starting at 3 incrementing by 1 each time.

Comment: Hello, correct. B1 source cell, then first dependency B3, next B4 etc. for C1 source cell it would be C3, then C4 etc.

Comment: One thought I had when using your solution. If I wanted in the result sheet, the row above the dependencies (Row 2) to also display a possible header in Row 5 of the source sheet, what code would I need to add? I assume it could be added to the loop. Pls let me know if that requires a separate Question/Post

Comment: Try `Cells(2, j) = r1.parent.name` inside the r1 loop.

Comment: Parent.name seems to return the name of the sheet. e.g. Sheet1 Sheet1
$M$3 $M$3

Comment: Might make sense to start a new question if only because code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: @sjr what would be the code to skip to the next cell if a cell does not have a dependency? It should still list the cell but then leave the cell below it empty. Currently I encounter an error at this line: `For Each r2 In r1.Dependents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I would suggest replacing my variable names with more useful ones. I haven't included a check that a cell has any dependents which is advisable as otherwise it will probably error.

```
Sub ListDependents()

Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Use InputBox to prompt user for range.
'Test for cancel and a single-cell selection.

Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
    Title:="Please select a range", _
    Prompt:="Select range", _
    Type:=8)

On Error GoTo 0

'Test for cancel.
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Test for single-cell selection.
'Remove comment character if single-cell selection is okay.

If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "You’ve selected more than 1 row. Please select contiguous cells per row only."
End If

'rng.Select to confirm selection
MsgBox rng.Address

Sheets.Add().Name = "Dependents"

'add first cell of range in B1, second in C1 etc until end of range
'then add first dependent of first range cell in B3, second in C3 etc
Dim ra As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

j = 2
For Each ra In rng.Areas
    For Each r1 In ra
        Cells(1, j) = r1.Address
        i = 3
        For Each r2 In r1.Dependents
            Cells(i, j) = r2.Address
            i = i + 1
        Next r2
        j = j + 1
    Next r1
Next ra
       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to add the headers above each dependency. I moved the rows down by one to have space for a header and then used offset to match the respective header.

```
j = 2
For Each ra In rng.Areas
    For Each r1 In ra
       Cells(2, j) = r1.Address
       Cells(1, j) = r1.OffSet(-1, 0).Value
           
    i = 4
    
    For Each r2 In r1.Dependents
                   
       Cells(i, j) = r2.Address
       Cells(i - 1, j) = r2.OffSet(-1, 0).Value
                
        i = i + 2
    Next r2
    j = j + 1
  Next r1
Next ra
```